# Using variables in sed command

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to replace a particular string in a file using the `sed` command. However, it is not working. Structure of data in my file:

```
"SomeServerName": {
    "serverIP": "192.168.0.132",
    "serverPort": "9999",
    "active": false
}
```

In this, I want to change `active` status to **true** from **false** on the basis of IP which is a variable input I get from the terminal.

The sed command I have used is :

```
sudo sed -i "s/$someIP/!b;n;n;c\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ "active": true/" filename
```

Here, `$someIP=192.168.0.132`. In sed, if I replace $someIP with '192.168.0.132' it works fine. However, if I pass the variable, it does not work.

**EDIT**: Below is my whole script for the above sed:

```
#! /bin/sh

someIP=$(hostname -I)
sudo sed -i "s/$someIP/!b;n;n;c\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ "active": true/" filename
```

Comment: are you executing the command from script or commandline? where is someIP set? i am having trouble reproducing this behavior.

Comment: I am executing this from a script. I get the someIP by running the command hostname -I and then assigning it to the variable someIP

Comment: I am sorry. I have edited the sed command to exactly my requirement.

Comment: might want to try putting your $someIP into ${someIP} but im not postive on that

Comment: I read that, in order to expand the variables in script, I need to use double quotes. I have tried all the ways mentioned in the man page of sed command in order to use a variable.

Comment: yes, sorry i was just working on powershell stuff an its the opposite

Comment: @moore1emu I tried doing that as well. Did not work out!

Comment: You should use a JSON parser such as [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for this, not sed.

Comment: might want to echo the SomeIP to see if its returning the value you expect..

Comment: @moore1emu yes! It is.

Comment: Can you please run your script with `sh -x yourscript` to generate a trace log and update your post with the full, unabbreviated output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
sed -zE "s/($someIP[^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n[^\n]*\"active\": )false/\1true/g" filename
```

you can not literally "pass" a variable to sed. bash replaces $someIP in the argument with the string it refers to before it starts sed, i.e. it's a pass by value.

beware that $someIP does not just match 192.168.0.132 though, but also 192:168:0:132 or 1924168903132 because to sed '.' means "any character", if you don't escape it.

this command will work as long as the matched IP and the "active" setting have exactly two lines and otherwise unspecified content between them.

Comment: This treats the whole input as a single line and will change `false` to `true` everywhere. I assume the real input has more than one JSON object in it.

Comment: with the g flag it should, as long as every entry has this same basic structure. if things are more complex, i will agree with you that sed is simply the wrong tool.

Comment: The point is that since the whole file is treated as a single line, your command will turn it to `true` everywhere, but you'd want it just for the entry right after the IP address match.

Comment: it makes one replacement for each match found. but you are right, there is one major concern. if active was already set for one IP block the next block with active set to false would be affected. will fix.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `sed` solution. Note, you need to use double-quotes `""` for `sed` and escape any other double quotes in the search or replace strings.

```
 $ input_ip="192.168.0.132"
 $ sed -i "/$input_ip/{n;n;s/\"active\": false/\"active\": true/}" inputFile
```

This assumes, `active: false` string appears two lines after the `$input_ip`. `n;n;` skips two lines at the end of `$input_ip`.